# API for Windows Phone Games scraping

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, web-scraping, windows-mobile

I am building a database of windows **phone** games. I want to scrape that data. But I couldn't find any libraries or apis or documentation for this.

Please don't duplicate this question with this: [windows store api to access metro and phone apps information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632565/windows-store-api-to-access-metro-and-phone-apps-information)

Because that answer is related to windows PC apps only, not windows phone apps.