# Need Windows Phone Games scraping API

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, web-scraping

I am building a database of windows phone games. I want to scrape that data. But I couldn't find any libraries or apis or documentation for this.

Please don't duplicate this question with this: [windows store api to access metro and phone apps information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632565/windows-store-api-to-access-metro-and-phone-apps-information)

Because that answer is related to windows PC apps only, not windows phone apps.

Comment: I need all popular games

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you could get the most popular games:

**The Download and Parse part:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace TestAPI
{
    public class WindowsPhoneGamesScraper
    {
        static string[] categories = new string[]
        {
            "action-adventure/actionandadventure",
            "card-board/cardandboard",
            "classics/classics", 
            "educational/educational", 
            "family/family", 
            "music/music", 
            "platformer/platformer", 
            "puzzle-trivia/puzzleandtrivia",
            "racing-flying/racingandflying",
            "role-playing/roleplaying",
            "shooter/shooter",
            "sports-recreation/sportsandrecreation",
            "strategy-simulation/strategy",
            "xbox-companion/xboxcompanion"
        };
        static string[] types = new string[] { "xbox-games", "top-free-games", "new-games", "top-paid-games", "top-rated-games" };

        public static async Task<List<WindowsPhoneAppInfo>> GetWindowsPhoneApps(string store, Action<string> updateStatus)
        {
            return await GetWindowsPhoneApps(store, categories.ToList(), types.ToList(), updateStatus);
        }
        public async static Task<List<WindowsPhoneAppInfo>> GetWindowsPhoneApps(List<string> categories, List<string> app_types, Action<string> updateStatus)
        {
            return await GetWindowsPhoneApps("en-US", categories, app_types, updateStatus);
        }

        public async static Task<List<WindowsPhoneAppInfo>> GetWindowsPhoneApps(string store, List<string> categories, List<string> app_types, Action<string> updateStatus)
        {
            List<WindowsPhoneAppInfo> data = new List<WindowsPhoneAppInfo>();
            foreach (string category in categories)
            {
                foreach (string type in app_types)
                {
                    updateStatus(string.Format("Downloading Category {0} and Type{1} Total:{2}", category, type, data.Count));
                    data.AddRange(await ScrapeAppsFromUrl("http://www.windowsphone.com/" + store + "/store/" + type + "/" + category, true));
                }
            }
            return data;
        }

        public async static Task<List<WindowsPhoneAppInfo>> GetNewWindowsPhoneGames(string store, string category = "")
        {
            List<WindowsPhoneAppInfo> data = new List<WindowsPhoneAppInfo>();
            data.AddRange(await ScrapeAppsFromUrl("http://www.windowsphone.com/" + store + "/store/new-games/" + category, false));
            return data;
        }
        public async static Task<List<WindowsPhoneAppInfo>> GetFeaturedWindowsPhoneGames(string store)
        {
            List<WindowsPhoneAppInfo> data = new List<WindowsPhoneAppInfo>();
            data.AddRange(await ScrapeAppsFromUrl("http://www.windowsphone.com/" + store + "/store/featured-games", false));
            return data;
        }

        private async static Task<List<WindowsPhoneAppInfo>> ScrapeAppsFromUrl(string p, bool handlePaging)
        {
            List<WindowsPhoneAppInfo> data = new List<WindowsPhoneAppInfo>();
            string res = "";
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            try
            {
                TaskCompletionSource<string> tcsDownloadedText = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
                client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sen, ev) =>
                {
                    if (ev.Error != null)
                        tcsDownloadedText.TrySetResult("");
                    else
                        tcsDownloadedText.TrySetResult(ev.Result);
                };
                client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(p, UriKind.Absolute));
                res = await tcsDownloadedText.Task;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(res))
                    return data;
            }
            catch (Exception x) { }
            try
            {
                var list = res.Split(new[] { "<td class=\"small\">" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                foreach (string item in list.Skip(1).ToList().Take(list.Length - 2))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var xelem = XElement.Parse("<td class=\"small\">" + item.Replace("</tr>", "").Replace("<tr>", ""));
                        WindowsPhoneAppInfo wpai = new WindowsPhoneAppInfo(xelem);
                        data.Add(wpai);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //Log the errors if you need
                    }
                }
                if (res.Contains(@"id=""nextLink""") && handlePaging)
                {
                    var lista = res.Split(new string[] { "id=\"nextLink\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    string url = "http://www.windowsphone.com" +
                                 (lista[1].Split(new string[] { "\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]);
                    List<WindowsPhoneAppInfo> apps = await ScrapeAppsFromUrl(url, handlePaging);
                    data.AddRange(apps);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Log the errors if you want
            }
            return data;
        }
    }

    public class WindowsPhoneAppInfo
    {
        public WindowsPhoneAppInfo(XElement xelem)
        {
            var elements = xelem.Elements("a").ToList();
            Title = elements[1].Value;
            var xAttribute = elements[1].Attribute("href");
            if (xAttribute != null)
            {
                Url = xAttribute.Value;
                AppID = Url.Split(new[] { '/' }).Last();
            }

            var imageLogo = xelem.Descendants("img").FirstOrDefault();
            if (imageLogo != null)
            {
                var logoURLAttribute = imageLogo.Attribute("src");
                if (logoURLAttribute != null)
                    LogoURL = logoURLAttribute.Value;
            }
            if (xelem.Descendants("div")
                    .ToList()
                    .Any(
                        elem => elem.Attributes("class").ToList().Any(att => att.Value.Contains("ratingSmall"))))
                Rating =
                    xelem.Descendants("div")
                        .ToList()
                        .First(
                            elem => elem.Attributes("class").ToList().Any(att => att.Value.Contains("ratingSmall")))
                        .Attributes("class")
                        .First()
                        .Value.Split(new[] { ' ' })
                        .Last();
            Price = xelem.Descendants("div").Last().Value;
        }
        public string AppID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Url { get; set; }

        public string LogoURL { get; set; }
        private ImageSource _logo;
        public ImageSource Logo
        {
            get
            {
                if (_logo == null)
                    _logo = new BitmapImage(new Uri(LogoURL, UriKind.Absolute));
                return _logo;
            }
        }

        public string Rating { get; set; }

        public string Price { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
            return Equals((WindowsPhoneAppInfo)obj);
        }
        protected bool Equals(WindowsPhoneAppInfo other)
        {
            return string.Equals(AppID, other.AppID);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return (AppID != null ? AppID.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }
    }
}
```

The sample:

```
List<WindowsPhoneAppInfo> data = await WindowsPhoneGamesScraper.GetFeaturedWindowsPhoneGames("en-US");//, categories.ToList(), types.ToList());
data.AddRange(await WindowsPhoneGamesScraper.GetWindowsPhoneApps("en-US", UpdateAction));
data = data.Distinct().ToList();
lboGames.ItemsSource = data;
```

You can call the same action with all the supported cultures.