# Get the version of windows phone app in store

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I'm developing a windows phone application. I have a version of my app in windows store. I know how to find the version of package I'm developing, but i want to find programmatically the version of my app in windows store,so i can compare and if the version store is bigger than the version of app user has, i want to make a notification and tell him that a newer version is available.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The OS will do this periodically for you already. If you have a breaking change that you need to make (for instance to a web service that your app consumes), you *could* add a method on that that passes the app version to determine if you think you've released a later version.

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with WP8 you can query the Store using [windows.applicationmodel.store.listinginformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.listinginformation.aspx) but sadly this does not include the version.

There is no public Windows Store API that provides this info. So you'd have to either scrape the info yourself or connect to a 3rd party API that provides alreasy scraped data. Solutions outlined here: [windows store api to access metro and phone apps information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632565/windows-store-api-to-access-metro-and-phone-apps-information)

**Wait but why?**
If you only need to provide your app the latest version code, just store it in a JSON file hosted on your backend, or alternatively, if you're feeling fancy,  create a dedicated webapp that checks for updates.

Comment: That does not return the currently published  version number

Comment: Yes, it has information only about: age, current market, app name, description. It doesn't show the package version of app.

Comment: Updated answer. Thanks!